# "Guidance" tag is unclear

Tags: discussion, tags

As it currently stands the [guidance](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guidance) tag has no description and could be interpreted many ways. There are currently 5 questions tagged with it:

1. [Coordinate systems](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/38991/1696), not sure how it's related.
2. [Navigation equipment](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/36143/1696)
3. [Ground marshals](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/25493/1696)
4. [DO guideline examples](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23058/1696)
5. [Checklist best practices](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/16793/1696)

Seems like it's being used as a synonym for both "navigation" and "advice." Should we just get rid of it? Are there better tags we could use?

**Edit:** Per the feedback I removed the tag from these questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would get rid of it; the word "guidance" by itself is far too broad/vague. There are so few questions that I don't think that's a big deal to do that.

Comment: I agree. Can you think of good replacements?

Comment: @fooot I don't think we need any. All the questions have other, more useful (IMO) tags, so I would just remove guidance without replacing it.

Answer (score 1):

It does seem an unusual tag. The only thing I can think of in aviation that "guidance" would relate to would be weapons systems